# Round to nicer numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number

The standard way to round numbers is to choose the nearest whole value, if the initial value is exactly halfway between two values, i.e. there is a tie, then you choose the larger one.

However where I work we round in a different way.  Everything is measured in powers of two.  So wholes, halves, quarters, eights, sixteenths etc.  This means our measurements are always a binary fraction.  We also round to binary fractions.  However when the value is exactly halfway between, instead of rounding up we round to the "nicer" number.

For example if I measure 5/8 but I need to round it to the nearest fourth, both 2/4 and 3/4 are equally close to 5/8, but 2/4 = 1/2 which is a nicer number so we round to 1/2.
If I measured 7/8 and needed to round to the nearest fourth I would round up to 8/8 = 1.

To put it concretely if we express every number as \$x\times2^n\$ where \$x\$ is odd, then we round towards the number with the larger \$n\$.

Going back to the example: I measure 5/8 and I need to round it to the nearest fourth.  The values I can choose are \$2/4=1\times2^{-1}\$ and \$3/4=3\times 2^{-2}\$, since -1 is larger than -2 we round towards that.

When both the options are fully reduced fractions you can think of this as rounding towards the fraction with the smaller denominator. However this intuition becomes a little bit strained when the options are whole numbers.

### Challenge

In this challenge you will receive 3 numbers. An odd positive integer \$x\$, an integer \$n\$ and an integer \$m\$.  You must round \$x\times2^n\$ to the nearest integer multiple of \$2^m\$ using the process described, and output the result as a binary fraction.  This can be either a native binary fraction or the \$x\times2^n\$ format used for the input.  The input will always be fully reduced so that the numerator, \$x\$, is odd, however you are not required to do so for your output.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

| \$x\$ | \$n\$ | \$m\$ | ⇒ | \$x\$ | \$n\$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -3 | -2 | ⇒ | 1 | -1 |
| 3 | -1 | -3 | ⇒ | 3 | -1 |
| 9 | -3 | 0 | ⇒ | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | ⇒ | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | ⇒ | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | ⇒ | 1 | 5 |

Answer (score 9):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Round[2^#2#,2^#3]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/NC8l2ihO2UhZB0gax6r9DyjKzCuJVta1S3NwUI5VqwtOTsyrq@aqNtXRNdbRNarV4aoG0oZAHohpCRJVMAAxDXUUgEwTKNMEyjSGinLV/gcA)

Returns a binary fraction. By default, the built-in [`Round`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) rounds to even.

Comment: Reading the docs on Round: "Round rounds numbers of the form x.5 toward the nearest even integer" got me wondering: Why does it work this way?  It seems perfect for this challenge, but the much more common rule is to round up.  I assume there is a deeper mathemetical reason for this?  Also, what if you do just want to round up in Wolfram?

Comment: One answer I found is to avoid systematic bias in data sets that have many 0.5 values.

Comment: @Jonah https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2116/6652

Comment: @alephalpha Thank you!  That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
f(x,n,m)int*n,*x;{for(;*n<m;++*n)*x+=*x&(*x/=2)%2;}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZFdasMwDMfZY3MK0dFgOw6rkxY2vNykMEYalzxYG6kLgtCT7KUvPdR2milOsq5gYf310xf217V-O9T15XI9BZc_f5dOkEbtZYtBoVZke_fRCavw1dssUygVZZWiVCh6qgq5Kux5LP15sI_7xrXYQGiOQZDRgGyejQr2Cwk97JIFdwaCCsjYWSJLvEnP0t9kx9KJlDSkyP1kBJ8dIyeWqz3w2QWYHFzO4_jmK2afk8S_tyhknyziclsNecnGSbxebqSdwBA0IyzvwMsYhHWsgPUfGNQANnpgsL0Dm9Gi-3_GXGGmiukN52_4BQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>39</sup> 32 bytes

```
((]*%<.@+1r2*2|<.@%)2&^)~(*2&^)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6/CsIwEIfn5imuQu0ftTZJIyQoCIKTk3vtIBYVVBCHDOLq7iP6IvGSBmoDl7vv@x0hZyNDRatZqGQck0EeN7BQEMMYClBYkxxW283aJEmVRfN8OaJ3lrEnTlHKhrv0lWS2TU1KDvvjDWqmoQGhoebaG24NXjX1pkCW3UKJSKFP5R9xl@nTAz@owZ@r7xfonS4nAoIJx2IQfN8fCCjOlFhD28RZx0S2puhWC0JdWHqFkbCq7JQl@x7vKWF@)

*-7 thanks to the round toward even idea from att's Wolfram answer*

Divide \$x2^n/2^m\$, manually round toward even, then multiply back \$2^m\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 29 bytes

```r
\(x,n,m)c(round(x*2^n/2^m),m)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZA9DoIwGIbj2J7ChOWrgdhSSHTgAl4BYakWjbEmBAg3cHd1QROP4UUcPYmF8tM4NE2f5_3aN70_8uYpo1dZSG_13kLtKvdMBOSXUu2gXvipWvrpmWhoMp_ZRkLoIo_r5RMHfa83xJDHsIQWsVb1mBu8Nmk6hqmGOqdZ0DOKQsOCiTEUmDu5zUKMHWcuDntxwlkkSyWK40VBRaqYJbpuFfsJzsDuSKIoAwGorcYI6exUdbDcsmNja5T2big-KOqicFKBrVh3GN7jf0pPmS9tGrP_AA)

Based on [@att's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256361/55372) and similar [`round`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html) behaviour in R.

Outputs non-reduced answers in `(x,n)` format.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <del>55</del> 51 bytes

```rust
|x,n,m|((n..m).fold(x,|x,_|x/2+(x&1&x/2)),m.max(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBRasMwDP3vKbR-BIkp2RK3sLW0-9slxhiFzhCI1ZKl4JH4JP3Jx3aoXmDnmO1ka6nAkv2kp2fp-FUfPpr-tNYCZlMKErQT8BZd9d6AXiTbT4FnwVIVPB5K139PghUk34dGpw8n1VkWNh2iZJmhTO-qLVr26Ftn74pbtEme-AsRm8xsLArRSP0Jeku9qwFjD4JS4CX-IhjOgxykaghFEOZzVnksP1dcph7_WfeXcM7gSbMraHYFqbEqIq_jaoLt61KaSm5wqrG1jqGV4IwL62gXT27KoP0kIAyGaBmJbuKGaft-iL8)

Copied from [@matteo_c's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256358/91213)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 214 bytes

```
\d+
$*
,(1+),(?!1\1).*
,$1
,(-1+),\1.*
,$1
,(-1+)(1+),\1
,0$2,$1
,-(1+),(1*)
,0$1$2,$2
,(1*),\1(1+)
,0$2,$1$2
+`01
100
\G1(?=.*0)
0
(?=0+,1+(0+))\1
1
^(?=1*0*,1+(0+)\1)(11)*.\1
1$&
(1*)0*,(1+0+,)?(-?)(1*)
$.1,$3$.4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xDsIwDER3/wVSQHHiRL62DAwoY38iQkWCgYUB8f/BaWFgOd29s5287u/H89r2fl5avUVygcQjsviyQwVnyw7GUocVf9lvjETdsNK0rSJwZ@h0oDXbWO9@o4bjoiCoUp3hyzkHZVIyp1EQvUZmOw26GELQ8IX2Jw9wyL10B@rHrbTjtsfFp8Lr@y5D3Ojy1NpR0ihpIBOYpVPPSpBRJtPJdOz@Aw) Link includes test cases. Output is not normalised and input is not required to be normalised either. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
,(1+),(?!1\1).*
,$1
,(-1+),\1.*
,$1
```

If `n` is greater than `m` then just delete `m`. Most of the rest of the code will then do nothing.

```
,(-1+)(1+),\1
,0$2,$1
,-(1+),(1*)
,0$1$2,$2
,(1*),\1(1+)
,0$2,$1$2
```

Subtract `n` from `m`, adjusting for their signs.

```
+`01
100
```

Calculate `2` to that power.

```
\G1(?=.*0)
0
(?=0+,1+(0+))\1
1
```

Divmod `x` by that.

```
^(?=1*0*,1+(0+)\1)(11)*.\1
1$&
```

If the remainder is at least half (for odd results) or more than half (for even results) then add another `1` to the result.

```
(1*)0*,(1+0+,)?(-?)(1*)
$.1,$3$.4
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≧×Ｘ²⁻ηζθ≧⁺∧⁻﹪θ²⊘¹⊘¹θＩ⟦⌊θζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY67CsIwFIZ3n@KMJxAHW7dORRA7VIK4iUNsSxNIkzaXCn35mOIidTsf5781gtvGcBVjpcfgr2F4dRYnUux@WWx4SVzzsXRO9vome@HxLofOUWDmnf4ZhVrq4FBQWAihMP0bmApJX@oWv9LatEEZnChkyXDhau5aPJDNvQYxK7XHE3ceH2dlzLo39TwJKWLMIYdj3M/qAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is not normalised and input is not required to be normalised either. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input `x`, `n` and `m`.

```
≧×Ｘ²⁻ηζθ
```

Scale `x` by `2ⁿ⁻ᵐ`.

```
≧⁺∧⁻﹪θ²⊘¹⊘¹θ
```

Prepare to floor `x`, but if its remainder modulo `2` is not `0.5`, add `0.5` so that it gets rounded instead.

```
Ｉ⟦⌊θζ
```

Output `x` and `m`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b/docs/info.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
o*Io/ò‚
```

Port of [*@pajonk*'s R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256372/52210), which is based on [*@att*'s Wolfram Language answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256361/52210).

Inputs in the order \$n,x,m\$; outputs as pair \$[n,x]\$. Just like the ported R answer, it does no additional reduction to its simplest form.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/X8szX//wpkcNs/7/1zXmMuXSNQIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZVF//O1Dq3L1z@86VHDrP86/6OjdY11THV0jWJ1onUNdYx1dI1BLGMdSx0DIMNYx1DHBEibQGljoAqT2FgA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E (built in Python), where `ò` does banker's rounding. In the new version of 05AB1E (built in Elixir), `ò` seems to be a regular rounding builtin, using the 'away from zero' convention for rounding halves.

```python
o        # Take 2 to the power of the first (implicit) input `n`
 *       # Multiply it to the second (implicit) input `x`
  Io     # Push 2 to the power of the third input `m` as well
    /    # Divide the earlier x*2**n by this 2**m
     ò   # Banker's round it to the nearest integer
      ‚  # Pair it with the (implicit) third input `m`
         # (after which this pair is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
(x,n,m)=>x*2**(n-m)*N/N;N=3e-324
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@1@jQidPJ1fT1q5Cy0hLSyNPN1dTy0/fz9rP1jhV19jI5L81V66trpF1cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGm4apjq4xUBcQgaWN0aSNdXQNEdIGaLKWKJpN0GQNdfBKmuCWNIbr/A8A)

Take `x,n,m`, return new `x` and set new `n` to input `m`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

```
2@*z22@/ZvZP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrjBy0qoyMHPSjyqICIEJQmQXLdY25TLl0jSBcAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E (legacy) answer, which is a port of pajonk's R answer, which is based on att's Mathematica answer.

Thunno is also built in Python so the rounding will work as intended.

```python
2@*z22@/ZvZP  # Implicit input
2@            # Raise 2 to the power of the first input, n
  *           # Multiply with the second input, x
   z22@       # Push 2 to the power of the third input, m
       /      # Divide x*2**n by 2**m
        Zv    # Round to the nearest integer
          ZP  # Pair with the third input, m
              # Implicit output
```