# Half even rounding

Tags: code-golf, number

The `round` function in Python 3 will round values of the form \$k+\frac{1}{2}\$ (with \$k\$ being an integer) to the nearest **even** integer, which is apparently [better than the rounding method taught in school](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior/10825998#10825998)

Your task is to recreate this functionality: write a program of function that given a (real) number as input, outputs that number rounded to the nearest number, using the same tie-breaking rule as [Python's round function](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhab02xzEnOTUhIV8qyK8kvzUjTyNCEyN63T8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzV0DY10DI00rbgUFAqKMvNKNNKUqjP1TWoVYkoUdO1AZHWaBlBAs1YJagTMEgA)

### Examples/Test-cases

```
-3.0   ->    -3
-2.7   ->    -3
-2.5   ->    -2
-2.2   ->    -2
-1.7   ->    -2
-1.5   ->    -2
-0.7   ->    -1
-0.5   ->    0
0.0    ->    0
0.4    ->    0
0.5    ->    0
0.51   ->    1
1.0    ->    1
1.2    ->    1
1.4999 ->    1
1.5    ->    2
1.7    ->    2
2.0    ->    2
2.3    ->    2
2.5    ->    2
2.6    ->    3
```

### Rules

- Please add built-in solutions to the community wiki
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution wins

Comment: What do you mean "better than the usual rounding method"?  Nearest-even *is* the usual method and has been for decades.  As the linked answer says, it's the default rounding mode for IEEE-754 FP math.  (Including for rounding to the nearest representable float after operations like `*` and `+`, as well as for rounding to integer-valued float with [C functions like `nearbyint`](//stackoverflow.com/a/47347224), or as part of conversion to integer with C functions like `lrint`.  If you're talking about C's `round()` function which rounds away from 0 as a a tie-break, that's not "standard".)

Comment: @PeterCordes Usual in the sense that the rounding mode taught in school (and used by the `round` method in C/Java/JavaScript) is to always round up (for positive numbers) if the last digit is `5`. The first time I heard about nearest-even rounding being commonly used was when I searched why Pythons round was not doing what I expected it to do (`round(0.5)` not evaluating to `1`).

Comment: Ok, fair point that it's not just C where a function called `round` is the simpler strategy of rounding [away from zero as a tie-break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_away_from_zero); I guess this strategy was at least formerly considered "usual" by high-level language designers.  I'd previously assumed C's `round` function was just a bad ancient design choice, and I've always thought of `lrint` and `nearbyint` as the normal rounding functions after investigating to find out they were the ones supported by hardware features on CPUs like x86, but I guess I'm weird :P

Comment: Exceedingly similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256353/round-to-nicer-numbers.  I'd probably say its a dupe.

Answer (score 11):

#### Builtins in various languages

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ò
```

Only works in the legacy version of 05AB1E, which is builtin in Python. The new version of 05AB1E, which is built in Elixir, will round away from zero.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Kb//3WN9EwB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w5v@6/yP1jXWM9DRNdIzBxGmIMJIR9cQxDUEcQ1ALAMgywCozEDPRAfCNjXUMQQKGAIVG@qZWFpa6oBUg7QZAYWN9Ix1QIYZ6ZnFAgA).

## C, 5 bytes

```
lrint
```

The [Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrint.3.html) lists this as being part of the C99, POSIX.1-2001, and POSIX.1-2008 standards.  It can be used without a prototype for golfing since it returns `long`, unlike the 4-byte [`rint`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rint.3.html) which returns `double` and thus can handle the full range of `double` inputs.  Both these and `nearbyint` use the current rounding FP mode, which is nearest-even by default on IEEE-754 systems, unlike [C's `round` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html) which uses away-from-zero as a tiebreak (like Python 2's `round`).

C++11 includes the C99 math library (which many C/C++ implementations already provided).  Since you need prototypes anyway in C++, `std::rint` or just **`rint` 4 bytes** should be available after `#include <cmath>` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint)).

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 17 bytes

```cs
x=>Math.Round(x);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69CsIwFEb3PsUdE6qlDk79WQQnu@jgHJO0XmiTkpuUSumzx4C4nAOHb/gkHSXJGAjNAI8PeT1VWTaH14gS5CiIYHZ2cGKCDf6dvPBJi0UFnUDDOGxZdg1G1sqmiT781PZNXJu2E/5d3G0wiq28ir11bBEOsCkrrE8Jec7hYg3ZURdPh17f0GjWM8zL4qw4T4/2PX4B)

The build in Math.Round in C# already rounds to the nearest even number

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 13 bytes

```cs
round-to-even
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU3P0GBPP3crhdzEkgy9tNK85JLM_LxihYKi1JKSyoKizLwSheLUwtLUvOTUYgVrLq5qBSM9UwVDIAbSBoZAlomlpaVCrUL00tKSNF2LtUX5pXkpuiX5uqllqXkQseWxQOMLFPQgvAULIDQA)

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 6 bytes

```forth
fround
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco7DoAgEATQnlNM6CF@wAISLwOuVkKInH9Ft3ozk6HSnsuc9MEBBKZW@p0ZUQVUpAbKvYIsrIbZocdnlKjUZP2BqmZhEVbBCV7YhNTG4P7ILw)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 5 bytes

```hs
round
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmvq6sQ878ovzQv5X9uYmaegq1CSj6XAhAUFGXmlSioKIDlFIz0TLGIGuuZ/v@XnJaTmF78XzfCOSAAAA) From the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:round):

> `round x` returns the nearest integer to `x`; the even integer if `x` is equidistant between two integers

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```hs
ær0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxDYAwDARXSYuUWLaTgDIBQyBKGpSKjgnYhEUymOHdnN9n/3n0fpuN92KL45lWsy1l4hiS0uKsTv0pbsQNe2ZkxjtTAXytEoNACmpCpbWGWYG/prgpZaAC8/4B)

## [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX), 4 bytes/1 instruction

```hs
␗�␄�
```

The replacement characters are in order the output and input registers; Unicode control pictures have been used to encode unprintable characters. This is `FINT $x,ROUND_NEAR,$y`, which rounds a float to the nearest integer (half-even).

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 22 bytes

```powershell
[Math]::Round("$args")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRaoMwFIbvfYqDhKEQi8a6YqEgjO1ubLRjN6UMZ08nw83ORDbofHaXxM4mnrvvP3@@hBzrb2x4iVUVFHWDPTmsTv32Phflbrlc1@3n3nNJ3rxx1@87x8k8B@TQzAviWUghiP0xYLPFNEhkwMyA2UGkj1jB5EioG5EZyEY4cqheYeLcxkk5iShcZJE6bCKzcZ6mqZ1IHTNwYSJTNhNjGxMbrynIv/LhF@7q5jYvyuDh9R0LASfdIQK5eM6rFikQ/DnKDe5hBeRlWDfI20rI4IocjLJebh83Ny0X9cdg3GWDUs2mLQrkXInOhgC/LheMPfdJGkErXVW2L1Cz/n/AWaQXndP1fw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 20 bytes

PHP's `round` has a third parameter "mode" that can be used with the constant `PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (value: 3)

```php
<?=round($argn,0,3);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsJADEX3OUZxYaETkkyrDFXc9RTdFBXrZmaoen1jgpvP@5@X1LWqni7nrXzybb9btkfuqIvtqPfrWpo5N6OGiARB8OgxeAgE9speyYmMyDTCHv48MLANbDJjn1ICt/1MbBaM4M8ED99S38@SXxqmHw)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 5 bytes

```python
round
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZLi_JL81Ig7JtuaflFChUKmXkKRYl56akausYGBjoKYMLIVNNKoaAoM69EI02pukJBX8HQwEDPoFZB106hOk0DLqBZq6QJMW3BAggNAA)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 5 bytes

```r
round
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZLi_JL81Ig7JuqJTa6xamFGrrGOsY6ekammlzJSZl5KRolOsWJBQU5lUBGmqYmRPGCBRAaAA)

## Rust, 25 bytes

Using libmath

```rust
math::round::half_to_even
```

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```php
V
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```php
ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmZIiwiIiwiMVxuMS41XG4yXG4yLjVcbjNcbjMuNVxuNCJd)

Comment: Edit in other built-ins that do this exactly.

Comment: C `double rint(double)` should work, too, with implicit conversion of the integer-valued `double` return to integer.  Except if the double value is out of range for the integer type you assign to, in which case the conversion is undefined behaviour.  (In that case [`lrint`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrint.3.html) has an "unspecified" return value, but not undefined behaviour.).  Oh but I guess for code-golf, you can get away without prototyping `lrint` in typical calling-conventions where `long` and `int` are compatible enough.  But a function returning `double` needs a prototype.

Comment: Related: [Problems casting NAN floats to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10366485) re: it being UB, and [unsigned conversion in C works as expected on x86 but not ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925860) for an example of what happens in practice.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Uses the `Math.round()` built-in, then clears the least significant bit of the result if the squared fractional part of the original input is \$1/4\$.

```javascript
v=>Math.round(v)&~(v*v%1==.25)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BToMwGAfwO0/xZYm2daOBMjTTFE9608uO6gFZ2TCMzlJIjNEnMPHiUd/D59kL@AjYohkwSEh@fP/v3z7EdVwmKttot5AL0aS8qXl0FesVVbIqFrgmh6@4PqoPfM4pC0mjxGOVKYFHaTkiVIl4cZnlYv5UJNgjVMu5VlmxxISWmzzTeHRbmFgq1UWcrHAJPIJnByAXGm6gnoCsNNwBh/I/j9wIEbqON/i6Wt8LRSYmbR8lzDKk5kJn5k8ii1LmguZyie1kDMi8Y2jBeVt7Dujn@337@WG@CE4Bbb/eEDHrL6RxA@qZUjey1W7guIye7DnszKzZwH4/33qY9/pz37qbe47Xnt7jdMhwj/6OvuP3dy3ZkNPZbNZjr4o5f7fekfWrLIMhwyGPOwa/)

#### Explanation

`Math.round` does *rounding half up*.

We have 4 cases. Given \$k\ge 0\$:

- \$2k+1/2\$ is rounded to \$2k+1\$. Clearing the LSB turns it into \$2k\$.

  Example: \$22.5 \rightarrow 23 \rightarrow 22\$
- \$2k+1+1/2\$ is rounded to \$2k+2\$. Clearing the LSB leaves it unchanged.

  Example: \$23.5 \rightarrow 24 \rightarrow 24\$
- \$-(2k+1/2)\$ is rounded to \$-2k\$. Clearing the LSB leaves it unchanged.

  Example: \$-22.5 \rightarrow -22 \rightarrow -22\$
- \$-(2k+1+1/2)\$ is rounded to \$-(2k+1)\$. Clearing the LSB turns it into \$-(2k+2)\$.

  Example: \$-23.5 \rightarrow -23 \rightarrow -24\$

Comment: What rounding mode does JS's `Math.Round` use?  Is it like C/C++'s `round()` function that rounds away from 0 as a tie-break? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_away_from_zero / [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347224)) . 
 Unlike C `nearbyint` and `rint` / `lrint` which use the current FP rounding mode, thus usually the one the OP wants.  I guess JS doesn't have equivalents for those, unless you're avoiding using a buitin.

Comment: @PeterCordes `Math.round()` does _rounding half up_ (23.5 -> 24, -23.5 -> -23). [Here is the official spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.round).

Comment: Thanks.  So `Math.rint()` isn't part of the standard, since that official spec doesn't include it.  But still, if it's available in some implementations maybe someone should add it to the community-wiki answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is very late but, Java and JavaScript are not the same language, nor are they really at all similar besides some syntax (confusing, I know), and therefore any methods that exist in Java may have no connection to JavaScript. There is no `Math.rint()` in any common JS implementation.

Comment: @noodleman: Oh crap, I do know that; maybe I left "javascript" out of my search terms since I ended up with one JS link (https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/reference/r_wpdr_standard_math_rint_r.html which might be some specific library?) and the other a Java link about Java's `Math.rint()`, and even more embarrassingly managed to type Java instead of JS in that comment.  Deleting it, thanks for spotting the noise and confirming that there's no common JS `Math.rint()`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

Jelly's builtin is 3 bytes: `ær0` - round to nearest multiple of \$10^0\$, which employs Python's `round`.

```
Ḟ,ĊḂÞạÞ⁸Ḣ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnk6R7oe7mg6PO/hroWH5z1q3PFwx6L/OofbNd3//4/WNdYz0FHQNdIzB5OmYNIISBqCRQzBIgZgtgGIbQBSbqBnAiLAXFNDHQVDkKAhSJuhnomlpSWINgURQG1GIDkjPWMQYQoizGIB)**

#### How?

```
Ḟ,ĊḂÞạÞ⁸Ḣ - Link: float, X
Ḟ         - floor {X}
  Ċ       - ceil {X}
 ,        - pair -> [floor(X), ceil(X)]
    Þ     - sort by:
   Ḃ      -   is odd?
      Þ   - sort by:
     ạ ⁸  -   absolute difference {X}
        Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
0".@":]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc6xCgIxDIDh3acIXQ5BQ5JePVo4EAQnJ3dxEA9xufef6sEl0txQyveTlH5rwG6CsUAHByAoyzkiXO63a6WA51Aedb97vz4zPCOMMC0Xkg@CgwaxkLZBfODtCv9XeA1kE2ROrck@Yew9dZiN3Jpt2Siefc55LaIleQ4txV4zRk/djcpT/QE)

Formats to zero decimal places and then evaluates back to number.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
<.@+1-:@~:4|+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BCsIwDIDhu08RvAyZC0naOlocDARPnnwBD@IQL76A@Op1sEaaHUr5fpLSV95iM8GQoIE9EKT5dAin6@Wcjzi23KXxm/ynTXm3edyfb7g5GGCaLyQbBPsSRENYB7GB1yv8X@ElkE6QOtQm/YTSW5ZhVnJt1mWlWPoY41KklGDZ1xR9Teksy64rPOQf)

Evaluates `floor(x + 0.5)` unless `2*x%4 == 1`, in which case `floor(x)` is returned instead.

```
<.@+1-:@~:4|+:
          4|+:   2*x%4
    1   ~:       != 1
     -:@         / 2
   +             x +
<.@              floor()
```

Comment: `0".@":]` is a brilliant find, and the other one is a nice golf too.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>35</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(x)(x+.5-!x%%2-.5)%/%1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGK3Mqi_NK8FNulpSVpuhbbYzQqNDUqtPVMdRUrVFWNdPVMNVX1VQ0hsjdNS2x0i1MLNXSNdYx19IxMNbmg2jVKNLkSc3I0EFxbWxhLE6J5wQIIDQA)

Comment: That is very well done, comparing to my naive approach! BTW, [-2 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGK3Mqi_NK8FNulpSVpuhbbYzQqNDUqtPVMdRUrVFWNdPVMNVX1VQ0hsjdNS2x0i1MLNXSNdYx19IxMNbmg2jVKNLkSc3I0EFxbWxhLE6J5wQIIDQA).

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup>38</sup> <sup>37</sup> <sup>34</sup> <sup>27</sup> 23 bytes

```
{*r-2!r*=/r:|1_:\x+0.5}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxdzjkPwiAUAOD9/QrERHoI5SiaYjxW1s4k1aXuDMZE7W9XatJCl5f35Z29eRWeypUvjpU3b9EZ9yw50x+ACqhiHCFETyhEBVSy/cJ6tgyWiUXcPzrt53FdBM91Dny8HrFOqRcUEwWIeDZQpqybpokYrZLw/3qijFcFqpQ65W6mAgdgjejsZTNk9rwluHIO5yRbra3h5nrz9wcSOWT20OamZITgMIodsQDtgFz/S74IAEdm)

-1 : Shuffle
-3 : Shuffle
-7 : Rework
-4 : Wow

Comment: ```f:{r-(2!r:_x+0.5)*</~-/|1_:\1(2*)\x}``` is 34 but is @Arnauld’s idea.

Comment: Even shorter without my reflexive use of hooks…

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 61 bytes

```
([02468])\.5$|\.[0-4].*
$1
\b9+\.
0$&
T`9d`d`.9*\.
\..+

-0
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDsIwDET3@46CSqtYdpoU/AX8AFtTKaAysHRAjPx7sMVyenc6@97Pz2u/t0N/ra1fOKb5sp4K5e5baOGQVhrQCcpDx0Lg7ohb1a1ulXSwoBCNQGBwa0EpI0zECJHOLtklIohbcctObMRWY0r4cxaIBWJloaSq8LafRYsjTfBnkWbYxg8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
([02468])\.5$|\.[0-4].*
$1
```

Remove the `.5` after an even digit, and any decimal less than `.5`.

```
\b9+\.
0$&
```

If there is an all `9`s integer part with a decimal part, prefix a zero.

```
T`9d`d`.9*\.
```

If there is a decimal part then increment the integer part.

```
\..+

-0
0
```

Remove any decimal part and change `-0` to `0`.

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 46 bytes

```
([02468])\.5$|\.[0-4].*
$1
\d+\..+
$.(*__
-0
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDsIwEEN3f0eRQqtYd2lSyBfwEU1VkGBgYUCM/Hu4E4tlW@/O78fn@bppP4TLtYdVUl7O27GxDN/GVWLeOGJQtPvUyAkDw7jviALpPVYWxJmCmHhyKS4JUT2qR3En5sQwYcbfF4VaoQYrc60VTvtZsjpxhj9LXGAbPw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
([02468])\.5$|\.[0-4].*
$1
```

Remove the `.5` after an even digit, and any decimal less than `.5`.

```
\d+\..+
$.(*__
```

If there is still a decimal part, remove it and increment the integer part.

```
-0
0
```

Change `-0` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>22</s></sup> 21 bytes

```
<.@+&1r2([-AND)1=2|+:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc6xCsIwEIDh3ac4HKylNuQuTUuCAUVxEgdXBwexFBfB2XePheYk1yGE7@cu5BWXqugheChgAxr8eGoFh@v5FLdqV63wQ@tbvb8cSwz0rXwsF8/H8Ia7gQD9eCktA6kuBeJg54FkwPkK/ldwCponNNvm1vwJZiOZhpGJuZGXmSTZOOemQqlYyS4n8WtMI5l2TWIbfw)

Heavily inspired by Arnauld's approach, except checks for exact 0.5 by doubling and checking that the remainder mod 2 is exactly 1 `1=2|+:`.

Then subtracts the adjustment bit `AND`ed with the standard round from the standard round.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 57 bytes

```r
\(x,a=x%/%1)`if`(x-a<.5,a,`if`(x-a>.5|a%%2,ceiling(x),a))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3LWM0KnQSbStU9VUNNRMy0xI0KnQTbfRMdRJ1YDw7PdOaRFVVI53k1MyczLx0jQpNnURNTagBDiU2usWphRq6xjrGOnpGpppcyUmZeSkaJTrFiQUFOZVARpqmJldiTo4GkoCtbVF-KUgVzJwFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{_x+0.5-1=4!2*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxdzr0OgjAQAOD9nqLUxILY2muphhp/1q7MTdAFdwdDYuTZtZhAy3K5L/fb2Xfbl1IYjqcqU5v+A7ADroUkhPAzCVEDV+KwsJmtglVijPtHp/0yrmPwXJcgx+sRq5RmQZyIgPFsoEpZ1XUdMVql4P/1RBWvCtQpTcr9TA0ewFls3XU95O6yZXTnPS1Ynq2clfZ2fz5eBAvI3bEpbCkYo2GUeuYAmoH47pd8AUxCRRc=)

A near-port of my own J answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [nearest-even rounding mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even), aka Banker's Rounding, is the default for IEEE-754 math, so normal programs (which haven't changed the FP environment) on most ISAs including x86 can just use instructions that round a float to an integer-valued float, or convert to integer with the current rounding mode.  (Most programs don't change the rounding mode away from the default.)

This is basically just using built-ins, but I didn't want to clutter up the existing answer with a bunch of machine-code stuff and associated interesting stuff I wanted to write about x86.  If people want to add sections for other ISAs, feel free, although most other mainstream ISAs have fixed-width instructions so it's always either a 2 or 4-byte instruction.

For the convert-to-integer instructions, out-of-range inputs produce the most-negative 2's complement integer of whatever destination width, which Intel calls the "integer indefinite" value.  (e.g. `0x80000000` for 32-bit.)  For AVX-512 unsigned conversions, the "integer indefinite" value is all-ones, `0xffffffff` (e.g. from [`vcvtss2usi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtss2usi).)  Rounding instructions that produce a number in the same format as the input don't have this problem.

## x86(-64) machine code, x87 scalar math, 3 bytes

Uses the rounding mode in [the x87 control word](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm), which defaults to round-to-nearest w. even as a tie-break.  (at reset and `finit`, and in fresh processes under normal OSes).

Input arg in `st0`, top of the x87 stack, result stored to an `int *` pointed-to by RDI (or EDI if the same bytes execute in 32-bit mode).  None of the standard calling conventions even for 32-bit mode pass FP args in x87 registers; unlike the SSE part of the answer, you couldn't write a C prototype to describe it to a C compiler.

```
  db 1f                   fistp  DWORD PTR [rdi]
  c3                      ret
```

Or to round to an integer-valued `long double` (modifying `st0` in place), [2-byte `frndint`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/frndint) is `D9 FC`.

## x86(-64) SSE2 or AVX scalar math, 5 bytes

These use the current rounding mode in MXCSR, the SSE math control/status register, which is fully independent of the x87 FP environment.  Both use the same 2-bit codes for four different rounding modes, ceil/floor/trunc and nearest-even.  (The Python 2 / C `round()` rounding mode is not directly available in hardware on x86, so [should be avoided for performance reasons unless you specifically want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c/47347224#47347224).  IIRC, ARM does have it in hardware, as well as IEEE standard rounding.)

All the relevant SSE / SSE2 / AVX conversion instructions are 4 bytes long, whether encoded as legacy-SSE or AVX, except for conversion into an MMX register.  SSE1 [`cvtps2pi mm0, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtps2pi) is `0f 2d c0`, allowing for a total 4-byte function if you're willing to return a 32-bit signed integer in the bottom of `mm0`, which is a pretty inconvenient place for it and would need the caller to use longer instructions to store or do math with it.

SSE1 `ps` instructions are only 3 bytes, but [`cvtps2dq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtps2dq) involves packed integers so was new in SSE2 along with `cvtpd2dq` (packed-double vs. packed-single, converting to a double-quad-word of packed integers).  SSE1 scalar instructions have an extra prefix, so SSE1 `cvtss2si eax, xmm0` is also 4 bytes, same as SSE2 `cvtsd2si eax, xmm0`.  An AVX encoding of all of these is available with 2-byte VEX prefixes (plus opcode + modrm byte), again for 4-byte instructions, except there's no `cvtps2pi` (MMX destination.)

```
                          sse:       # first arg in XMM0, return in EAX
    f3 0f 2d c0             cvtss2si eax,xmm0         # SSE1
    c3                      ret

Alternatives:  # float vs. double, and scalar vs. packed.
    f2 0f 2d c0             cvtsd2si eax,xmm0         # SSE2 scalar double to i32, note same 0f 2d opcode but different prefix from SSE1 scalar.
       0f 2d c0             cvtps2pi mm0,xmm0         # SSE1 2 floats to 2 i32 in an MMX reg
    66 0f 5b c0             cvtps2dq xmm0,xmm0        # SSE2 packed conversion 4 floats to 4x i32.  cvtpd2dq (2 doubles to 2 i32) is the same size

    c5 f9 5b c0             vcvtps2dq xmm0,xmm0       # AVX encodings; different bits in the C5 ... prefix represent different combinations of prefixes.
    c5 fa 2d c0             vcvtss2si eax,xmm0
    c5 fb 2d c0             vcvtsd2si eax,xmm0      ... etc.
```

(There are also truncating versions of these, like `cvttsd2si`, to implement C `(int)double` rounding semantics of truncation toward 0 without having to change the rounding mode like in the bad old days of x87 before SSE3 `fisttp`.)

Implementing C `rint[f]` / `nearbyint[f]` (rounding to an integer-valued `double` [or `float`]) needs multiple instructions until SSE4.1 `roundsd` / `roundps` etc, which are 6-byte instructions (with register args and no REX).  e.g. `66 0f 3a 0a c0 00       roundss xmm0,xmm0,0x0`.  (roundss and roundsd have separate opcodes, instead of being distinguished by prefixes like SSE1 `addss` vs. SSE2 `addsd`).  The instruction needs an immediate to specify the rounding mode: whether to override or not, and if so, which of the 4 modes to use, and whether to suppress FP inexact (precision) exceptions.  See [`roundsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundpd) documentation.  An immediate of `0` selects rounding-control = from the immediate, with the `00` field being the nearest-even mode that's the default.

(Like the "alternatives" above, I'm showing machine code + assembly of multiple instructions.  You'd only ever use one, depending on the input format (float or double, scalar vs. packed).)

```
66 0f 3a 08 c0 00       roundps xmm0,xmm0,0x0        # other than SSE1, the ps form isn't shorter.
66 0f 3a 0a c0 00       roundss xmm0,xmm0,0x0
66 0f 3a 0b c0 00       roundsd xmm0,xmm0,0x0

c4 e3 79 0b c0 00       vroundsd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0,0x0      # 3-byte VEX prefix needed for instructions in opcode "maps" used by SSE4 and later, i.e. with 3 prefixes such as 66 0f 3a
c4 e3 79 08 c0 00       vroundps xmm0,xmm0,0x0   ... etc.
```

## x86 + AVX-512 not relying on the current rounding mode, 7 bytes

**AVX-512 EVEX prefixes can override the rounding mode on a per-instruction basis**, for *any* instruction with scalar or 512-bit vector width, including when `vaddps` or whatever have to round their result to a representable float/double.  (Not 128 or 256-bit vector width until [APX and AVX10.2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) which finally stops caring about obsolete 32-bit mode so it can use more of the bits of the EVEX prefix, instead of having to slot in to only invalid-in-32-bit-mode encodings of some instruction.)  Fun fact: out-of-order exec CPUs that support SMT (e.g. hyperthreading) already have to track the rounding mode on a per-instruction basis internally, because different logical cores could be using different rounding mode settings.  So it makes some sense to expose this functionality to programmers.

AVX-512 also allows for conversion directly [to unsigned integer, and to *packed* 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592329/convertion-of-four-packed-single-precision-floating-point-to-unsigned-double-wor), not just scalar-only for conversions involving 64-bit signed integers in SSE/AVX (in 64-bit mode only).

An [Intel manual from 2016](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/319433-024-697869.pdf) when AVX-512 was newish has some details in section 2.5.4 *Static Rounding and Suppress All Exceptions*, where it compares to instructions like `vroundps` and `vrndscaleps` which allow this via an immediate, vs. setting MXCSR.

```
                         avx512:
    62 f1 ff 18 2d c0       vcvtsd2si rax,xmm0{rn-sae}
    c3                      ret
```

The NASM syntax I used is `vcvtsd2si  rax, xmm0, {rn-sae}`.  The disassembly is from `objdump -drwC -Mintel`, so is using GAS's `.intel_syntax noprefix` style for the rounding override.

Using an `eax` destination wouldn't save any machine code bytes, unlike with legacy SSE (separate REX prefix), or with AVX where `vcvtsd2si rax,xmm0` needs a 3-byte VEX prefix for a total length of 5 bytes instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⊟⌊Ｅ⟦⌊θ⌈θ⟧⟦↔⁻θι﹪ι²ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsMgFIXhvU/heAVTSqFTphIodLBkDxlMKu0F9Rr19vWtnuk/8O1fk3YyrtZniFxe7Deb4JDjaU4YCkwmF5gpgsaAnj1oE2F5OKKulJgsOgyf1qsSy33L5LjYrjnDoQTKhjS92RGgEtf2cJV9Y63D5Xyrw8/9AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @JonathanAllan's Jelly answer.

```
Ｎθ                      Input as a number
        θ               Input number
       ⌊                Floor
          θ             Input number
         ⌈              Ceiling
     Ｅ⟦    ⟧            Map over both values
               θ        Input number
                ι       Current value
             ↔⁻         Absolute difference
                  ι     Current value
                 ﹪      Modulo
                   ²    Literal integer `2`
                    ι   Current value
            ⟦           Make into list
    ⌊                   Take the minimum
   ⊟                    Pop the rounded result
  Ｉ                     Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

34 bytes for arbitrary precision:

```
≔⪪θ.η≔⊟ηζＩ⁻ＩΣη∧⎇﹪ＩΣη²¬‹ζ5›ζ5∨№θ-±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCoMwEEX3PYW4moBKW3DlSlx0U61gLxA0aCAmdpIU6uXTsXZROjAwvP9gfj9x7A1XIZTWylFDtyjp4JFEcRazJJpYcfgmrVlgIrQSalFqBxW3Dmqpvd3Pzs9kkFLqAe4CNccX1GbwyvwJZ9rGOLgKa2GlZ3m84QsK7gT@kBtCZbzeG6Vbo0aM5MCJfaYIIT1meUif6g0) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪θ.η≔⊟ηζ
```

Separate the integer and decimal parts.

```
Ｉ⁻ＩΣη∧⎇﹪ＩΣη²¬‹ζ5›ζ5∨№θ-±¹
```

Compare the decimal `>=` or `>` than `.5` depending on whether the integer is odd or even, and increment the absolute value of the integer if so.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 17 bytes

```javascript
v=>v*(k=3e-324)/k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BToMwGAfwO0/xZZe2bq1QNg2a4kmPXnZUD8jKxDGKhZEY4xuYePGo7@Hz7AV8BGzRbGWQNPnx/b9/eUzapE51XjW0VAvZZaJrRdwe4ZUIJQ35lByvOi2fNrmWeJTVI8K0TBZXeSHnz2WKfcIaNW90Xi4xYXVV5A0e3ZYmlil9maQPuAYRw4sHUMgGbqCdgNo0cAcC6v88ojEibJ1U@HqzvpeaTEzaPlqaZchwS87Nl1SVtSokK9QS28kYkHnH0EOIvvYC0M/3@/bzw5wIzgBtv94QMeuvpKMh800pjW01DT3K2emBZ3tzaz5w4OZ7D/O@Ow@s93Pf8/vbHU6HnB0w2DHwAnfXkg85jaLIoVPFvb@/3pG7VZbhkLMhT/YMfwE)